# trying to create ie9 friendly version of working code

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a multipush menu which is great ... it has a js file that you can add classes of things that also get pushed when the menu is activated, which is also great... problem is ie9 doesn't understand the jquery plugin and i am trying to create a i.e9 snippet to help here is the original code ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // HTML markup implementation, overlap mode
    $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu({
        containersToPush: [$( '.tile-area-title'), ( '.navbtn'), ( '.tile-area-main' ), ('#logo-title'), ('.submenu-ctn')],
        collapsed: true,

        // Just for fun also changing the look of the menu
        wrapperClass: 'mlpm_w',
        menuInactiveClass: 'mlpm_inactive'
    });
```

this is the code for the .navbtn when clicked do some stuff which also works with all browsers...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $navToggle = $('.nav-toggle');
    $(".navbtn").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if($navToggle.hasClass('active')){
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
            $navToggle.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand');
            $navToggle.addClass('active');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });

    $(".navbtn").hover(function () {
        $('.nav-toggle').addClass('hover');
    },function(){
         $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('hover');
    });

    $('#menu').on('click', function(e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
    });


    $('body').on('click', function(e){
        $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
        $navToggle.removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

But I have added in this i.e9 detection and do stuff script which i have appended to the above code ...

```
if ((old_ie > -1) || (new_ie > -1)) {
            ms_ie = true;
            }
                if ( ms_ie ) {
               $(".navbtn").click(function (e) {
              ({
        containersToPush: [$( '.tile-area-title'), ( '.navbtn'), ( '.tile-area-main' ), ('#logo-title'), ('.submenu-ctn')],
        collapsed: false


    });
                }

)}
```

but it doesn't work... all I want to do is push a couple of classes on the screen when the menu opens/closes can someone help out ?

EDIT :-

When the menu button is clicked f12 developer options reveals the folloowing ....

```
multilevelpushmenu.js, line 612 character 6
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'defaultView': object is null or undefined
```

and that relates to this code in the js file ...

```
// Push container(s) of choice
            function pushContainers( absMove ) {
                if( instance.settings.containersToPush == null ) return false;
                $.each( instance.settings.containersToPush, function() {
                    var lMr = parseInt( $( this ).css( 'margin-left' ) ),
                        lM = isInt( lMr ) ? lMr : 0,
                        rMr = parseInt( $( this ).css( 'margin-right' ) ),
                        rM = isInt( rMr ) ? rMr : 0;
                    $( this ).stop().animate({
                        marginLeft:  lM + ( ( instance.settings.direction == 'rtl' ) ? (-1) : 1 ) * absMove,
                        marginRight: rM + ( ( instance.settings.direction == 'rtl' ) ? 1 : (-1) ) * absMove
                    });
                });
            }
```

... so i am thinking the function pushContainers is not right for ie9 ?

Comment: You sure it's the JS not working? Don't really see anything there that IE9 wouldn't understand, sure there isn't a CSS issue?

Comment: well in f12 developer options it is saying when the button is clicked that ... "Unable to get value of the property 'defaultView': object is null or undefined 
" on every time the button is clicked , and relates it to jquery  hng on i will post it

Comment: I don't see `defaultView` anywhere in the posted code...

Comment: me neither it is pointing to the beggining of instance.settings.containerToPush, function

Comment: maybe i need to create a bespoke script to drop in when the button is clicked that says simply for i.e9 move a couple of classes and ignore the functions altogether ?

Comment: i mean, in effect it's only purpose is to move containers to the right when the menu opens and then back again when it closes.. maybe a simple javascript animation will compensate for ie9 not getting it  ?

Comment: although having said that this works ! http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/demo/basichtml/basichtml.html